# Using stacks in Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I'm building a site using Laravel 8 and Jetstream. Jetstream is opinionated about the javascript / css framework, which is great, but I'm needing to add an external javascript library to one of my components, and I don't see anywhere to add them in the default `app` layout. So I added a stack for the css /js like this in the default app layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        // head stuff
        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">

        @livewireStyles
        @stack('css') // added this stack

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
        // body stuff
    </body>
    @stack('scripts') // and this stack
</html>
```

Then in my child view that extends the app layout, I'm trying to push the js file to the js stack:

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Stuff & Things') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>

    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
                <x-component.stuffnthings />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
@push('scripts')
    <script src={{public_path("js/mobiscroll.javascript.min.js")}}></script>
@endpush
```

When I view source, the js file isn't there in the child view. What am I missing? Is this the right way to add custom js / css to Jetstream or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone banging their head against a similar wall-- the problem with my code is that the `push` needs to be inside the layout tag. Once I moved that up, it worked (and I had been using `public_path` wrong):

```
<x-app-layout>
<x-slot name="header">
    <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
        {{ __('Stuff & Things') }}
    </h2>
</x-slot>

<div class="py-12">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
            <x-component.stuffnthings />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@push('scripts')
    <script src={{"js/mobiscroll.javascript.min.js"}}></script>
@endpush
</x-app-layout>
```

I'll leave this open in case there's a better way to accomplish this!

Comment: The reason you have to add it to the `app-layout` component is because the `stack` will be evaluated before the `push` directive. Once a `stack` has been evaluated you can no longer push to it. So when you call `app-layout`, the content (`$slot`) you added inside is evaluated and the `push` is executed. After that the contents of `app-layout` (and therefor the `stack`) are evaluated and the `<script>` is pushed to the `stack`. If you leave it outside of the `app-layout` tag, it is evaluated after the `app-layout`, rendering it useless.